# Binding template to data to get html text in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a strange issue when using `$compile(element)(scope)` to bind some data to a dom element manually.

Please check the [example code here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/xm3TFfGcbarwSAeSzERb?p=preview)

In the example preview, when you click the button "Bind Template", the template is compiled with some data and rendered into a dom element. But when the button is clicked again, only the template is shown. Any idea what could be the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying to do doing it this way, but you should probably use a directive instead.

[Here is your plunker working with a directive](http://plnkr.co/edit/y9VdgskB2XAJ3eIqF5wJ?p=preview)

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $templateCache, $compile) {
        $scope.name = 'World';
        $scope.result = '<empty>';

        $scope.bindTemplate = function () {
                $scope.item = {
                    CaseNumber: 1234,
                    CandidateName: 'Joe Smith',
                    CandidateEmail: 'joe@smith.com',
                    IsActive: true
                }
        };

});

app.directive('caseDetails', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: "template.html"
    }
})
```